# Azure Application Insights Pricing

Tags: azure-application-insights

As part of an Enterprise Agreement, how can the data ingestion pricing (per GB) from one Application Insights instance be different from the data ingestion pricing of another Application Insights instance?

Both Application Insights instances are deployed as classic-based instances (so no commitment tier), and both are deployed in the same region. The different pricing per GB is also shown in "Usage and estimated costs" of the Application Insights instance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have created 3 Function Apps in the Consumption Plan with different App Insight Instances and in the same region:

[image]

Observing a little vary in the price from the "Usage+Estimate" Section for the Data Ingestion Service:

[image]

Then From this GitHub [Doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/usage-estimated-costs.md) of Azure Monitor, Whatever the Data Ingestion of App Insights Instance, its estimation of price/charges varies significantly based on the configuration of Application Insights.